# How to get token from Tower / AWX API?

Tags: python, rest, ansible, ansible-tower, ansible-awx

I'm trying to access AWX API from a script Python.
The documentation has the ressource **/api/v1/authtoken/** for that, however when visiting the URL:
https://myHost/api/v1/authtoken/
It says that it can't find the ressource.

I also tried:

```
response = requests.get('https://myHost/api/login/', verify=False,
    data = json.dumps({"username": "user","password": "pass"}))
results = json.loads(response.text)
token = results['token']
```

But I get a :

```
ValueError: No JSON object could be decoded
```

AWX version: 10.0.0

Comment: Well, have you printed out `response.text` to see what's in there? Did you call [`response.raise_for_status`](https://requests.readthedocs.io/en/v3.0.0/api/#requests.Response.raise_for_status) like a good developer? Did you even briefly consider including the **version** of AWX you are using? Please do read the [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) page

Answer (score 1):

[The fine manual](https://github.com/ansible/awx/blob/10.0.0/docs/auth/session.md#usage) says that:

> A GET to /api/login/ displays the login page of API browser

So `= requests.get(` is **for sure** not what you want; however, even if you were to switch to `requests.post` the very next line says:

> It should be noted that the POST body of /api/login/ is not in JSON, but in HTTP form format. Four items should be provided in the form:

so `data = json.dumps({` is also for sure also not what you want